# How to Set D3 Funnel Chart Label Legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to d3 funnel chart label legend in horizontal position.i mentioned only label name and value .I want label name with particular label color.Below i mention my sample code. Please someone review my example code and help.

```
var data = [
    ['L0', 4, '#080800'],
    ['L1', 5, '#702963'],
    ['L2', 0, '#6f34fd'],
    ['L3', 6, '#07fff0']
];

var options = {
    width : 600,
    height : 400, 
};

var funnel = new D3Funnel ( data, options );
funnel.draw ( "#funnelContainer" );
```

Comment: You may get a swifter answer if you post at the github page for the d3Funnel developer [here](https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel)

Answer (score 1):

You should have an attribute named labelColor to override on row-level and give it a valid hex.

> labelColor : string,  A row-level override for label.fill. Hex only.

Working example [D3 Funnel](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqvn8462k9)